# Encoding problem in chunk output when compiling R markdown on a mac

Tags: r, macos, r-markdown, knitr

When compiling this small R Markdown doc:

````
---
title: "Testing"
author: "Lars Relund Nielsen"
output: html_document
knit: (function(inputFile, encoding) {
  rmarkdown::render(inputFile, encoding = encoding,
  output_dir = "docs") })
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
#' Function for loading missing packages that install them if not already installed.
#'
#' @param packages String vector with package names
#'
#' @return NULL (invisible)
#' @export
#'
#' @examples loadPackages(c("MASS", "ggplot2", "tikzDevice"))
loadPackages <- function(packages) {
  newP <- packages[!(packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
  if(length(newP)) install.packages(newP, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
  lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE)
  invisible(NULL)
}
loadPackages(c("tidyverse"))
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
tbl1 <- tibble(name = c("Lars", "Susan", "Hans"), age = c(23, 56, 45))
tbl1
```

```{r}
sessionInfo()
```
````

using `rmarkdown::render("r-test.Rmd", output_dir = "docs", output_file = "index.html")`

The output looks like:

[image]

There seems to be an encoding problem in the output which disappears if I compile it on Windows.

Any hint on how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like your output is flooded with color codes. However, I cannot reproduce this (same R and OS). Maybe this helps: `options(crayon.enabled = FALSE)`

Comment: That works. In fact the code was compiled on a server using GitHub Actions which seems to create this problem.